# Page-numbering control with scrbook and fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, scrbook

Have I missed an instruction for specifying where the document class `scrbook` places the page number on the first page of each chapter of a book?

---

In a book with multiple chapters, involving diverse and complex formatting, I am using `scrbook`, for its support of `\multiplefootmarker`. I am also using `fancyhdr`, in order to control header content.

With `scrbook` and `fancyhdr` coexisting, I have a problem getting page numbers to appear centered on the first page of each chapter. `fancyhdr` centers page numbers as desired after the first page of a chapter. But it seems that `scrbook` defaults to placing page numbers on the bottom right of each chapter's first page, and that seems to override `fancyhdr`'s `\fancyfoot` command. A MWE follows (actual use of `\multiplefootmarker` isn't needed to illustrate the problem).

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook} % needed for use of \multiplefootmarker (not shown)

% Fancy *headers* are only needed on pages after first of chapter.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{Right header only needed on pages after chapter's first.}
\fancyhead[LE]{Left header only needed on pages after chapter's first.}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}

% But page number should be centered at bottom of every page.
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

% For MWE content
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Right Header Text}{Left Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
  \chapter{Another Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Right Header Text}{Left Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Following @Ulrike_Fisher's comment, I added a command

```
\newcommand\headrulecontrol{
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyhf{}\cfoot{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
  }
```

and then modified each chapter to, for example:

```
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Right Header Text}{Left Header Text}
    \headrulecontrol
    \lipsum[1-12]
```

This works fine — page numbers are centered but there is no page-head rule on the first page of a chapter.

Comment: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\cfoot{\thepage}}` see the documentation of fancyhdr.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, `fancyfoot` doesn't seem to be needed at all in the presence of `\fancypagestyle`. But, interestingly, a horizontal line now appears at the top of the first page of each chapter. I see that I can eliminate it with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`, but do I then need to restore an explicit head rule after the first page?

Comment: Oh, I see how to use `\renewcommand` for that a second time right after using `fancyhf`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ulrike mentioned you have to redefine the `plain` style in the preamble:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}% remove all entries in header and footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% centred page numbers in footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no headsepline on plain pages
}
```

Setting `\headrulewidth` to `0pt` for page style `plain` affects only the headrule on `plain` pages.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook} % needed for use of \multiplefootmarker (not shown)

% Fancy *headers* are only needed on pages after first of chapter.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}

% But page number should be centered at bottom of every page.
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For MWE content
\title{Book Title}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Left Header Text}{Right Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
  \chapter{Another Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Left Header Text}{Right Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed the header entries. On left pages (even page numbers) `\leftmark` is now used and on right pages (odd page numbers) `\rightmark`. So your `\markboth` commands can change the header entries. But the `\chapter` command sets marks too.

---

Maybe you want to use package **`scrlayer-scrpage`** which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook} % needed for use of \multiplefootmarker (not shown)

\usepackage[
    headsepline,
    manualmark% because of your manual usage of \markboth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
%\rohead{Right header only needed on pages after chapter's first.}
%\lehead{Left header only needed on pages after chapter's first.}
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For MWE content

\title{Book Title}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Left Header Text}{Right Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
  \chapter{Another Chapter Title}
    \markboth{Left Header Text}{Right Header Text}
    \lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

But do you really want to set the marks manually? If `\chapter` and `\section` should set the marks automatically, change option `manualmark` to `automark` and remove your `\markboth` commands.